# how can i find a date button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find a button in a date selector, I tried this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@day='5']")
```

the element is :

```
<button class="active" day="5" month="10" year="2021" aria-describedby="tooltiptext_5">5</button>
```

the clander look like this:
[clickhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkkTK.jpg)

the error msg when it trying to find the element:

```
[17756:20660:1004/113550.831:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(22
8)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if
 there is no report that this ends.
[17756:20660:1004/113550.831:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(23
1)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[17756:20660:1004/113550.832:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(23
4)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if
 there is no report that this ends.
[17756:20660:1004/113550.860:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(23
8)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "
", line 26, in <module>
    func()
  File "
", line 22, in func
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(DATE)
  File "
ib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_elem
ent_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "
ib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_elem
ent
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "
ib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "
ib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_
response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Una
ble to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@day='5']"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)
```

thanks a lot Adam.

Comment: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Una"

Comment: i add it , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting this error since you have given an input element for the xpath even though it's a button. So try this.

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@day='5']")
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be cause of lot of reason.

1. Element could be in an **iframe**.
2. Element is not rendered properly.
3. Element in not unique in HTMLDOM.

etc..

Please check in dev tool, if we have unique entry in HTML DOM or not for the below xpath.

```
//button[@day='5']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

if it's `1/1` matching node.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@day='5']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@day='5']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@day='5']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@day='5']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: thank you for the really detailed answer it probably will help me in this project!